# How do i load this API data into a dataset/dataframe so that i can make use of it?

Tags: python, pandas, api, statistics, dataset

```
while True:
    for symbol in symbols:
        base, counter = symbol.split('_')[0], symbol.split('_')[1]
        tickers = requests.get(last_price.format(base, counter))
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: If you want to wait five seconds between each ticker, your `time.sleep(5)` function needs to be indented one more level.  Also, no breaks are apparent in your code so this will run in a closed loop.  Finally, can you please provide a sample of the data.

Comment: can you further explain your question?

Comment: This loop is getting prices for me from a crypto api every 5 seconds. I want to store this data into a pandas dataframe. How do i do that?